# Rectangular to polar coordinates

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

Change the Cartesian integral into an equivalent polar integral, then solve it.

$$\int_1^{\sqrt{3}}\int_{1}^x\,dy\,dx$$

i could find $\theta$ goes through $\pi/6$ to $\pi/4$ using $\tan^{-1}\theta$=$\frac{y}{x}$ and points: ($\sqrt{3}$,1) and ($\sqrt{3}$,$\sqrt{3}$) or from graph
and area of triangle= 2-$\sqrt{3}$

x=rcos$\theta$ , y=rsin$\theta$ ,When x=1 and x=$\sqrt{3}$ r=sec$\theta$ and r=$\sqrt{3}$sec$\theta$

When y=1 and y=$\sqrt{3}$,  r=csc$\theta$ and  r=$\sqrt{3}$csc$\theta$

Which equations of r should i use and why?

what confuses me is that y=1 not 0,
if y was from 0 to x i would choose r to be r=sec$\theta$  and r=$\sqrt{3}$sec$\theta$ and $\theta$ from 0 to $\pi/4$ and area=1

[image]

Comment: Since the integrand is constant, try translating the origin of the coordinate system to the lower-right corner of the region of integration first, and then converting to polar coordinates.

Comment: Very weird question. Why would anyone want you to use polar coordinates for that? It's just the area of a triangle that you're after...

Comment: It looks like an exercise to practice the transformation rather than a practical application.

Comment: @amd why not the lower-left ? 
does it change if integrand was not constant?

Comment: @HansLundmark what if $$\int_1^{\sqrt{3}}\int_{1}^x\,x^2+y^2dy\,dx$$ ?

Comment: Then it would still be easier to do it in Cartesian coordinates directly. But maybe polar coordinates could be useful with some more complicated function of $x^2+y^2$...

Comment: @HansLundmark yes that's what i mean

Comment: so why don't you do it directly using Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: @Bhaskara-III i have already used it and the area was the same but that's the question

Comment: By placing the origin at the lower-right, $r$ ranges from $0$ to some fairly simple function of $\theta$. You only have to work out one non-radial boundary line instead of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given angle $\theta$ (between the bounds that you have found), the corresponding ray from the origin enters the integration domain when it intersects the line $y=1$, i.e. when $r \sin\theta=1$, and it exits when it intersects the line $x=\sqrt3$, i.e. when $r \cos\theta=\sqrt3$. So you get
$$
\int_{\theta=\pi/6}^{\pi/4} \int_{r=1/\sin\theta}^{\sqrt3/\cos\theta} \cdots
$$

Comment: You're welcome!